When I was running a java project with Pcap4j, it showed "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Structure"
I was writing a network packet capture project using java + Intellij IDEA + Pcap4j, so I create a maven project, and add dependencies like this:
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pcap4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pcap4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pcap4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pcap4j-packetfactory-static</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

And copy a sample code like this:

import java.io.IOException;
import org.pcap4j.core.PcapNetworkInterface;
import org.pcap4j.util.NifSelector;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String\[\] args)
    {
        // The class that will store the network device
        // we want to use for capturing.
        PcapNetworkInterface device = null;
        
        // Pcap4j comes with a convenient method for listing
        // and choosing a network interface from the terminal
        try {
            // List the network devices available with a prompt
            device = new NifSelector().selectNetworkInterface();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        System.out.println("You chose: " + device);
    }
}

However, when I run it, it shows:

D:\\computer\\JAVA_STUDY\\JDK\\bin\\java.exe -javaagent:D:\\TOOLS\\IDEA\\lib\\idea_rt.jar=63950:D:\\TOOLS\\IDEA\\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath E:\\JavaHomework\\Pcap\\target\\classes;E:\\JavaHomework\\pcap4j\\pcap4j-core-1.8.2.jar;E:\\JavaHomework\\pcap4j\\pcap4j-packetfactory-static-1.8.2.jar Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Structure
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at org.pcap4j.util.NifSelector.selectNetworkInterface(NifSelector.java:34)
at Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Structure
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 11 more

Process finished with exit code 1

what's wrong with it? How can I fix the problem?

Share the full pom.xml
